# Understanding the status in Systemctl utility

Tags: unix, rhel, systemctl

I have a service and i have created a service unit file to support the execution of the service in RHEL7.X

When i am running the service and then i am running the status command i am getting the below console output:-

```
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/spiritAgent.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2016-11-28 07:21:46 IST; 5s ago
  Process: 32708 ExecStart=/opt/MyService start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 495 (java)
   CGroup: /system.slice/My.service
            ‣  495 /usr/java/jre1.8.0_102/bin/java -DGW_STATUS_SCHEDULER_INTERVAL=600000 -Dcom.ibm.jsse2.JSSEFIPS=true -Dspirit.config.dir=/opt/.
```

Can anyone please explain me the meaning of '‣' here which is below the CGroup. Actually ' ‣ 'is a 'square' but when i am copying it here it is getting changed to ' ‣ '

Comment: You can copy and paste the symbol from here: └─

Comment: This is not the symbol i want to use the Symbol is like 'square'

Comment: You must be missing a font or some such. It's always a "tree branch" symbol that @DmitriChubarov posted. See also https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fragment of `systemctl status` output for another service. It should be clear now what each line means, but let me just comment briefly. The symbols are pseudographics for the comb that illustrates process hierarchy.

Here we have one cgroup and several processes assigned to it. Each process has its PID listed together with a prefix of its command line.

For example the first line is for `PID=2282` and commandline of apache worker.

```
  Main PID: 2282 (httpd2-prefork)
  CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─ 2282 /usr/sbin/httpd2-prefork -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -DICIN...
           ├─ 2735 /usr/sbin/httpd2-prefork -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -DICIN...
           ├─ 2736 /usr/sbin/httpd2-prefork -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -DICIN...
           ├─ 2739 /usr/sbin/httpd2-prefork -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -DICIN...
           ├─ 2740 /usr/sbin/httpd2-prefork -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -DICIN...
           ├─ 2741 /usr/sbin/httpd2-prefork -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -DICIN...
           └─17607 /usr/sbin/httpd2-prefork -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -DICIN...
```